# XCode 4.4 "Find in Workplace" broken

Tags: xcode, macos, search, find, osx-mountain-lion

When trying to find a word in a project, XCode 4.4 is not searching through all the files.

I try SHIFT-CMD-F, type the simple word "configure" (without quotes) and the status window says `Finding "configure"` (for about 1/2 sec...) then back to the last status it had (finished running...)

No results found is the message in the left column.

Any ideas?  Mt. Lion 10.8 & XCode 4.4

Thx

Comment: just to be pedantic - you do have the word 'configure' in your project, all in lowercase :) And this exact search worked in earlier versions of XCode? If you click on the tiny magnifying glass and select 'show find options' is there anything in there that looks odd/unexpected?

Comment: Yes, it is a tableview project which has `// Configure the cell...` so it should've matched (using previous 'context' of find).  re: the 'show find options' ... everything was unexpected because it was all reset from the previous XCode 4.3 settings (in a preexisting project).  Marked answer below as accepted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Click on the magnifying glass on the left of your search field and select 'Show Find Options', Uncheck 'Match Case'

Comment: Sounds easy...but when should a `dot` release reset previous settings!  :(  Anyway, this worked, BUT adding to this, under the "Find In" section, change to be a broader scope.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem in 4.5, it wasn't finding anything, and it wasn't a case issue. My solution was to delete derived data for the project, which seems to fix a lot of wierd behaviors when XCode gets wonky, and it worked for this as well.

To clear derived data, open the Organizer, select Projects, select the Project you want to clear, and you should see a "Delete..." button next to the file URL for the projects derived data.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are searching files in project then select "Ignoring case". Below is screenshot for the same.

[image: Screenshot for condition 1]

2. If you are searching a particular file then select magnifier -> Edit finding option.. -> Select/Unselect Matching case accordingly. Below is screenshot for the same.

[image: Screenshot for condition 2 - Step 1]

[image: Screenshot for condition 2 - Step 2]